# getline function not working

Tags: c++, getline

Can someone please tell me which header to use for using getline() in C++. I have used

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
```

none of them seem to be working.

Here is the entire code that I have written so far

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

class TextQuery
{
    typedef map<string, set<string::size_type> > word_map;
    TextQuery(ifstream &file)
    {
        FillLineVector(file);
        BuildMap(file);
    }

    void query(string);
private:
    word_map map;
    vector<string> LineVector;
    void FillLineVector(const ifstream&);
    void BuildMap(const ifstream&);
};

void TextQuery::FillLineVector(const ifstream& file)
{
    string line;
    while(getline(file,line)); //error:getline identifier not found
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Be more specific please.

Comment: please add code to your question, which is using getline.

Answer (score 2):

You need `iostream` and possibly `string` if that's the version you're using.  Why that doesn't work will have to remain a mystery since you provided no additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Post your code if you want people to be able to help you. Anyhow, getline should be used as such:

```
// getline with strings
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string str;
  cout << "Please enter full name: ";
  getline (cin,str);
  cout << "Thank you, " << str << ".\n";
}
```

As showed in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Answer (score 0):

Your functions take `ifstream` rather than `istream`, so you would have to include `<fstream>` to get the definition of that.

However, you're probably better off making the functions more generic by taking `istream`, unless for some reason they can only work with a file. In that case, you'll just need `<iostream>` and `<string>`, which you already have.